# PowerShell - XML - Append Multiple Elements to Node in Remote Desktop Connection Manager File

Tags: xml, powershell, nodes, appendchild

$xmlFrag = $NewXMLNode.innerXml

```
Cannot convert argument "0", with value: 
"<removed for ease of reading>" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Xml.XmlNode"."
At line:1 char:1
+ $node.AppendChild($xmlFrag)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

Does anybody have any ideas how I can fix this error? Or is there perhaps a better way to work within the XML file than the methods i am using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this: `$xmlFrag.InnerXml = $NewXMLNode.innerXml`

Instead of your original assignment `$xmlFrag = $NewXMLNode.innerXml`.

Your original assignment replace the xml fragment by a string so when you try to use the appendchild method with a string (instead of the fragment), it fails.

**Further explanation**

You can see the difference in types of resulting assignments by looking at the following standalone demonstration.

```
[xml]$NewXMLNode = "<xml></xml>"

#create document fragment to prevent error regarding no root node
$xmlFrag = $xDoc.CreateDocumentFragment()
Write-Host 'Wiping the fragment and assigning a string' -ForegroundColor Yellow
$xmlFrag = $NewXMLNode.innerXml 
$xmlFrag.GetType() | out-string | Write-Host

$xmlFrag = $xDoc.CreateDocumentFragment()
Write-Host 'Proper assignment of the node xml to the newly created fragment' -ForegroundColor Green
$xmlFrag.innerXml = $NewXMLNode.innerXml
$xmlFrag.GetType() | out-string | Write-Host
```

[image: demo]
The first example is the assignment you do. Since you can't provide a string to appendchild, it fails. The second assignment is what you need to do. XmlDocumentFragment type is preserved properly, which succeed when used with appendchild method.